# Django complex Query negation

Tags: django, django-queryset

I need to exclude some results from a queryset.  The conditions for this are that such that I want to exclude all records that `belong_to` a particular list of objects, but include those whom a second value is not a particular value (even if the record belongs_to one of the excluded records).

In SQL I'm imagining this would look like:

`SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE NOT (belongs_to_id IN [1,2,3] AND NOT foo=bar)`

I'm expecting this to work:

`qs.exclude(Q(belongs_to__id__in=[1,2,3]) & ~Q(foo=bar))`

However, when I check the result in `connection.queries` it appears that django is omitting the `~Q(foo=bar)` portion.

For reference this would do the same thing in pure Python:

```
included_ids = qs.filter(foo=bar).values_list('id', flat=True)
excluded_ids = qs.filter(belongs_to__id__in=[1,2,3]).values_list('id', flat=True)
filtered_excluded_ids = [x for x in excluded_ids if not x in included_ids]
new_qs = qs.exclude(id__in=filtered_excluded_ids)
```

I'd like to avoid having to use this solution since it results in extra unnecessary queries.

Comment: may you kindly provide the query returned by connection.queries?

Comment: do `qs.exclude(~Q(foo=bar), belongs_to__id__in=[1,2,3])` works?

Comment: as a second hypothesis is foo=bar always False (for whatever reason) in your records? (don't know if Django has this kind of optimizations)

Comment: SELECT * FROM "customer_customer" WHERE ("customer_customer"."deleted" = false  AND "customer_customer"."belongs_to_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119))

Is the resulting query.  Kinda baffling that it just drops the second part altogether.  And no in my results it would not always be false.

Comment: note I left out the customer_customer.deleted part in my original (it comes from an earlier query) and replaced all fields with * for simplicity

Comment: thank you for the info. It's quite strange indeed... have you tried the alternative syntax I've posted in the second comment?

Comment: It's way worse: SELECT * FROM "customer_customer" WHERE ("customer_customer"."deleted" = false  AND "customer_customer"."belongs_to_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119) AND NOT (NOT (("customer_customer"."sales_rep_id" = 1  AND "customer_customer"."sales_rep_id" IS NOT NULL))))

Comment: I just tried to reproduce this behavior with a UnitTest on a simplified model and was unable to, it worked perfectly as I expect.  I'm going to see if I can produce a test on a simplified model that reproduces the issue

Comment: It's a good idea. If you can reproduce it, I suggest you to open a ticket on code.djangoproject.com

Answer (score 1):

Given the unexpected results of Q I think you should use [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra)

```
qs.extra(where=['NOT ("customer_customer"."belongs_to_id" IN [%s] AND NOT "customer_customer"."sales_rep_id" = %d)'%(','.join(your_list),bar)])
```

sometimes the  Django query syntax by itself fails expressing a complex WHERE clause (it may depend even on the db backend...), but as I said this behavior it's quite strange.

and, if anything else fails (say, if your query will become even more complex), you may go down to [raw](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/).